# Puppeteer check through website content/elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I need to check through the elements of the website for my code, but I can't understand how to do it with puppeteer on Node.JS

Here's the code I tried:

```
if(page.content('input[data-kwimpalaid="1580983806648-1"]'))
    found = true
if(found = true)
console.log("I found it")
if(found = false)
console.log("I didn't found it")
```

So what I need basically, I have a website with element ID's ending in 1 to 20, and it can be random, and consecutive. For example it may start at 1, then has 6 ids (1,2,3,4,5,6) or it can start at 5 (5,6,7,8,9,10). I want to check for every ID, and if it exists then change the value of ''found'' to `true`. If the page doesn't have id 1, try id 2, id 3, id 4, etc.. until it finds an input with that ID/CLASS that exists on that website.

Shortly, I need to check if the selector element I use exists on the website or not (content).

Comment: For one, comparisons are done with `==` or `===`.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the docs, [`page.content()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pagecontent) returns a Promise that resolves to the entire HTML text. You need to run `page.$(selector).then(result)` instead to look for an element.

Comment: The one above was an example of what I'm trying to do. @ChrisG I'll check what you've told me and tell you if there's problems.

Comment: That sounds like your question is a "gimme the code" one, we don't do that here I'm afraid.

Comment: I didn't ask for  a code, I just want to understand puppeteer better, I wasn't sure this action was possible. No reason to dislike my question, it may help a lot of people who are new to puppeteer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, what about this? On top of my head!

```
let found = false;
const allInputs = page.content('input[data-kwimpalaid]');  // Assuming an Array of elements here

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    if (allInputs.find((input) => input.dataset.kwimpalaid.startsWith(i))) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (found) {
    console.log("I found it");
} else {
    console.log("I didn't found it")
}
```

So basically scan the document once for all elements with an ID.
Then look at each element individually.
The for-loop respects your preference.
If an element is found `Array.prototype.find` will return it. Otherwise, its return value is `undefined`.

I'm assuming here, that puppeteer behaves similar to DOM in browser. Someone else might correct me, if that isn't the case.

Comment: I'm getting the error `''allInputs.find is not a function''`

Comment: Hm, just checked the [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/5ffcde2b7b55b41f7fa462c01380d994d5ddf13f/docs/api.md#pagecontent). `page.content()` is returning a whole string (I assumed it being similiar to `querySelectorAll()`.

Could you use the [`$$`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pageselector-1) method?
`const allInputs = page.$$('input[data-kwimpalaid]');`